# EJB wraps my customExceptions throwed from interceptors

Tags: exception, ejb, cdi, interceptor, ejb-3.0

I'm studying interceptors and decorator and when experimenting with it I've encountered the problem that if I throw a checked exception from an interceptor, the EJBContainer wraps it as an EJBException, instead what I would like to show to the client is my custom exception.

Assume that I've one simple method and one interceptor that check if the parameters are valid like so:

```
@Interceptor 
public class TestIntercepor {
    
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object test(InvocationContext invCtx) throws Exception{ 
        
        try {
        
        //check parameters...
         
        return invCtx.proceed(); 
        
        } catch (CustomException ex) {
            throw new CustomException();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        
    }

}
```

The exception that I want to throw if something's off is CustomException:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

    public CustomException() {
        super("ERROR! Input fields not valid");
    }

}
```

now I've noticed in my SOAP Fault message that the exception throwed is an EJBException. I did some research and found out that the EJB Container wraps all the SystemException throwed, so I'm assuming that my CustomException throwed by the interceptor is treated as an uncecked exception for some reason, while if I throw the same exception from the business method, the client see exactly the right exception in the message.

I've even tryed to add the @ApplicationException annotation in my CustomException class for be completely sure that my Exception has to be treated as an ApplicationException instead of a SystemException, but it doesn't seem to be working.

There's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that if your custom exception extends RuntimeException instead of Exception it works. Seems like that the @ApplicationException work only if the exception is a System Exception like RuntimeException and not if extends normal Exception.

```
@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {

    public CustomException() {
        super("ERROR! Input fields not valid");
    }

}
```